# @jsonview of jackson not working with jax-rs

Tags: java, jackson, jax-rs

I have written following code:

```
class A{
    public static class Public { }
}

// Entity class
public class B{
    @JsonView({A.Public.class}) 
    int a;
    int b;    
}

public class C{
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @JsonView({A.Public.class}) 
    public Bed getData(){
        // return object of B
    }
}
```

I am expecting output as

```
{a: vlaue}
```

but i am recieving

```
{a: value, b: value}
```

Please let me know what is wrong in this code.

i am using jackson version 2.4.2

Answer (score 7):

The reason for this behavior is the `MapperFeature` [`DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/MapperFeature.html#DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION).

From the Javadoc:

> Default value is enabled, meaning that non-annotated properties are included in all views if there is no JsonView annotation

In Jersey you can disable this feature via the `JacksonJaxbJsonProvider`. This should work in a similar way for other JAX-RS frameworks.

```
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
  public MyApplication() {
    ...

    JacksonJaxbJsonProvider provider = new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider();
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.disable(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION);    
    provider.setMapper(objectMapper);

    register(provider);

    ...
  }
}
```